# Duplicate questions answered

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates

Just found something immensely interesting on ai.SE.

[First Question](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/9582/can-someone-suggest-me-a-platform-to-develop-a-mental-health-mobile-app-for-andr)

[Second Question:)](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/9542/can-someone-suggest-me-a-platform-to-develop-a-mental-health-mobile-app-for-andr)

**Both the questions are identical.** They are not just duplicate questions rephrasing eachother, **they are literally the same.**

I don't know how neither of them was not marked as duplicate by fellow users. *Moreover, the questions have received separate answers and upvotes too*. Does this raise any concerns to/from the community?

Comment: The community is short in community members for active moderation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at it, it looks like the OP didn't realise how user accounts work, or how the site works, so created a new account and a new post in order to be able to interact with the post.

I have flagged for the posts and the user accounts to be merged.

It's not a major issue - on a small site with few active members things like this happen, just vote to close as dupe or flag if necessary.

Comment: Yeah, I even I thought that was the case.

Comment: The questions have been merged, thank you both!